# Ambiguos indirect export: vuetify when doing " import {Vuetify} from 'vuetify' "

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, backend

I receive this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: Vuetify //app.js:4:9
[home.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyE4L.png) [app.js with the syntax error highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktWyn.png)

I think I tried almost everything: to importing Vuetify without '{}', in home.blade.php with {{asset('js/app.js')}} and it s the same error everytime.

Comment: There's no Vuetify named import in vuetify afaik. It's `import Vuetify`. You shouldn't put tech info to the title. It's seen that it's `import  {Vuetify}` in one place and `import Vuetify` in another

Comment: I used **import Vuetify** and it says the same error but now says : **Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default**

Comment: Do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are using a weird way to import vuetify, is there any reason for that? Maybe your real question is "How to import vuetify in Laravel-Vue"?